# show cassandra cluster space used, cluster read/write, cluster latency as shown by DataStax OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, nodetool

How can I show cassandra cluster space used, cluster read/write, cluster latency as shown by DataStax OpsCenter?

Table or Keyspace specific data is available through nodetool command but dont see any way to find the data related to cluster only.

Comment: for your application do you use any monitoring tooling like prometheus, graphite, or some service like datadog or new relic?

Comment: i want to show all data to my own web pages as graph and charts

Comment: there are many options, but its usually best to use what you use for other applications. ie if you use prometheus/grafana already then use it for C* as well.